# .Add does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, list, xamarin.forms

I'm creating my first app in Xamarin.forms and want to add information about the characters. I followed the Microsoft docs but I keep getting the error that ".Add does not exist in the current context"
I've been the last hour or two searching online but nothing seems to have fixed it. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CharCreator
{
    public class Character
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int charIndex { get; set; }
        public string charName { get; set; }
        public string charClass { get; set; }
        public string charRace { get; set; }
        public int[] charStats { get; set; }

        public int classId { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
    }

}

public class CharClasses
{   
    List<CharClasses> classList = new List<CharClasses>();
    classList.Add(new CharClasses() {classId = 1, className = "Barbarian"});
}
```

Comment: I read your question too quickly - the problem isn't LINQ, it appears that you're trying to execute code outside of a method body, which isn't allowed.  Although I would expect a different error message.

Comment: create a method in public class CharClasses then move your add to there.

Comment: also, I suspect you mean to use List<Character> not List<CharClasses>

Comment: I moved CharClasses into the CharCreator class and that didn't work. Changing the name of the list seems to break it as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem begins with the declaration

```
List<CharClasses> classList = new List<CharClasses>();
```

You are declaring a List of CharClasses instead of a List of Character. Then you try initialize this list with a first element. But you cannot add code outside a method.

So, if you really need to have *CharClasses* initialized with a *`List<Character>`* containig at least one element then you need to write this

```
public class CharClasses
{
    public List<Character> classList = new List<Character>()
    {
        new Character {classId = 1, className = "Barbarian"}
    };

    --- other class method follows

}
```

This syntax is explained in documentation at [Object and Collection Initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers)